Can ATC assign speed adjustment to aircraft on final approach course?
According to FAA Order 7110.65AA,
5−7−1.b. Do not assign speed adjustment to aircraft:
4. Inside the final approach fix on final or a point 5 miles from the runway, whichever is closer to the runway.
However, according to ICAO Doc 4444,
4.6.3.6 Only minor speed adjustments not exceeding plus/minus 40 km/h (20 kt) IAS should be used for aircraft on intermediate and final approach.
I thought ATC can't assign speed adjustment if the aircraft is on final approach segment.(after having passed FAF)
However, according to ICAO Doc 4444, is it possible?
In real situation, what procedure does ATC usually apply?

While the visual separation and the visual approach is widely used in the US, there is less requirement for controllers to issue speed adjustment instructions,I think.

This will depends on jurisdiction. ICAO suggests a limit of 4 NM final. DOC 4444:

4.6.3.6 Only minor speed adjustments not exceeding plus/minus 40 km/h (20 kt) IAS should be used for aircraft on
intermediate and final approach.


4.6.3.7 Speed control should not be applied to aircraft after passing a point 7 km (4 NM) from the threshold on final
approach.

This is widely adopted, including by EASA. AMC2 to ATS.TR.210(a)(3) of EU 2017/373:

(b) The air traffic controller should use only minor speed adjustments not exceeding plus/minus 40
km/h (20 kt) IAS for aircraft on intermediate and final approach.


(c) The air traffic controller should not apply speed control to aircraft after passing a point 7 km (4
NM) from the threshold on final approach.

As usual, the FAA does things differently from everyone else. 7110.65AA 5-7-1:

b. Do not assign speed adjustment to aircraft:


(...)



Inside the final approach fix on final or a point 5 miles from the runway, whichever is closer to the runway


It is very common for air traffic control to apply speed control on final approach, as this is an essential way of ensuring efficient spacing between arriving aircraft at busy airports.

I guess perhaps US airports are more generously sized on average so they don't need it that much. At some moderately busy EU airports with just a single active runway to work with, it's entirely commonplace to interleave arrivals and departures, so you frequently hear TWR tell a plane first in line for landing "ABC, reduce to minimum approach speed, break break, XYZ, cleared for immediate takeoff" (as in, "line up and GTFO"). Often enough followed shortly afterwards by "ABC, go around, traffic on the runway".

"Frequently hear" No way. You make it sound like the average European air traffic controller (I happen to be one) is completely incompetent.

Sorry, but I never said or meant to imply anything like that. Actually, I'm truly amazed how the ATCs at these airports manage to consistently stuff 40-50 movements an hour onto a single runway. But I have personally witnessed two such go-arounds because the departing aircraft started it's takeoff roll a little later than was needed and didn't clear the runway in time (out of a sample of some 70? landings) so it does happen.

This is a place where the US is different from ICAO recommendations. You can see some of those differences at the FAA's website:

In the US, speed control is not to be assigned inside Final Approach Fix or 5 NM from runway end.

